# Basic theory of exchange

Tags: free-trade

I'm looking for information about the basic commerce and trade. But all I've found is books about Free World Trade, Business Management and Economics. That is not what I'm looking for. I'm more interested in the concept of trade as it is, without specifics. For example, why people trade, what is the trade goal, on what circumstances you will gain from trade and when you are going to loose, how an opportunity for a trade is found etc.?

Comment: Any basic microeconomics book should say that trade is an exchange: I give you something and you give me something, and we both value what we have after the exchange more highly than what we had before; otherwise we would not have traded.  It may be dressed up as utilities, or marginal costs and benefits, or lubrication of commerce due to money and prices, or comparative advantage in international trade, or liquidity provision by middlemen, but fundamentally it is mutually beneficial exchange.